# checking file content contains javascript injection in java

Tags: java

can anyone help on how to do checking on uploaded file content for javascript injection.
For example: I have file name test.pdf and it contain html code inside like this

```
<html>
    <h1> pentest123</h1>
    <h2> testing 123 </h2> 
    
    <script> alert("javascript here!")</script>
</html>
```

been googling around also, but also need some advice from others.

Thank you